# How find this integral $F(y)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{(1+x^2)(1+(x+y)^2)}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Find this integral
$$F(y)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\dfrac{dx}{(1+x^2)(1+(x+y)^2)}$$

my try: since
$$F(-y)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\dfrac{dx}{(1+x^2)(1+(x-y)^2)}$$
let $x=-u$,then
$$F(-y)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\dfrac{dx}{(1+x^2)(1+(-x-y)^2)}=F(y)$$

But I can't find $F(y)$,Thank you

Comment: The answer is $\dfrac{2\pi}{4+y^2}$ . Indeed, you have already proven that $F(y)$ is even.

Comment: Hello,@Lucian,How find this integral?

Comment: What about partial fraction decomposition ?

Comment: Partial fractions, dear friend. $\dfrac{2x+3y}{(1+[x+y]^2)}-\dfrac{2x-y}{1+x^2}$

Comment: Does $y \in {\mathbb R}$ ?.

Answer (score 5):

How about using the residue theorem? We have
$$F(y)= 2\pi i \sum_{x^*} \mathop{\rm Res}_{x=x^*} f(x),$$
where the sum ranges over all the poles of the integrand $$f(x)= \frac1{(1+x^2)[1+(x+y)^2]}$$ in the upper half-plane. These poles are situated at $x^*= i, i-y$ (assuming $y$ to be real).

As the poles are simple poles, we obtain the residues by 
$$ \mathop{\rm Res}_{x=x^*} f(x) =\lim_{x\to x^*} (x-x^*)f(x) .$$
Thus, we have
$$ \mathop{\rm Res}_{x=i} f(x) = \frac{1}{2 i [1+(i + y)^2]}$$
and
$$ \mathop{\rm Res}_{x=i-y} f(x) = \frac{1}{2 i [1+(i-y)^2]}.$$

So, we obtain
$$ F(y) = \pi \left[\frac{1}{1+(i + y)^2} +
\frac{1}{1+(i-y)^2} \right] = \frac{2 \pi}{4+y^2}$$
as the final result.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Use first partial fraction decompositions. Then, integrate between $-a$ and $+a$. You should arrive to something like $$\frac{-\log \left((a-y)^2+1\right)+\log \left((a+y)^2+1\right)+y \left(\tan
   ^{-1}(a-y)+\tan ^{-1}(a+y)+2 \tan ^{-1}(a)\right)}{y \left(y^2+4\right)}$$ Simplify as much as you can and go to limits. You will arrive to Lucian's solution.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to evaluate the above integral is using the [Parseval's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform):

> Let $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ be integrable, and let $\hat{f}(\xi)$ and $\hat{g}(\xi)$ be their Fourier transforms. If $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are also square-integrable, then we have Parseval's theorem (Rudin 1987, p. 187):
>   $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \overline{g(x)} \,{\rm d}x = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \hat{f}(\xi) \overline{\hat{g}(\xi)} \,d\xi,$$
>   where the bar denotes complex conjugation.

You need the following fact:

> $$ \mathcal{F} \left\{\frac{1}{1+(x+y)^2} \right\}(w) =\pi e^{iyw}e^{-|w|}. $$

Check the different conventions of the [Fourier transform and its tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform).

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
With the identities:
\begin{align}
{1 \over 1 + \pars{x + y}^{2}}
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\delta\pars{x + y - z} \over 1 + z^{2}}\,\dd z
\\[3mm]
\delta\pars{x + y - z} &=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
\expo{\ic k\pars{x\ +\ y\ -\ z}}\,{\dd k \over 2\pi}
\end{align}
we'll have

> \begin{align}
> {\rm F}\pars{y}&
> =\color{#66f}{\large%
> \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\dd x \over \pars{1 + x^{2}}\bracks{1 + \pars{x + y}^{2}}}}
> \\[8mm]&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\expo{\ic ky}
> \pars{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\expo{\ic kx} \over 1 + x^{2}}\,\dd x}
> \pars{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\expo{-\ic kz} \over 1 + z^{2}}\,\dd z}
> \,{\dd k \over 2\pi}
> \\[8mm]&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\expo{\ic ky}
> \verts{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\expo{\ic kx} \over 1 + x^{2}}\,\dd x}^{2}
> \,{\dd k \over 2\pi}
> =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\expo{\ic ky}
> \verts{2\pi\ic\,{\expo{\ic\verts{k}\ic} \over 2\ic}}^{2}\,{\dd k \over 2\pi}
> \\[8mm]&=\half\,\pi\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\expo{\ic ky}\expo{-2\verts{k}}\,\dd k
> =\half\,\pi\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\cos\pars{ky}\expo{-2\verts{k}}\,\dd k
> =\pi\,\Re\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{\pars{-2 + y\ic}k}\,\dd k
> \\[8mm]&=\pi\,\Re\pars{1 \over 2 - y\ic}
> \end{align}

\begin{align}
{\rm F}\pars{y}&
=\color{#66f}{\large%
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\dd x \over \pars{1 + x^{2}}\bracks{1 + \pars{x + y}^{2}}}}
=\color{#66f}{\large{2\pi \over y^{2} + 4}}
\end{align}